# How does datepicker work on HTML onclick?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

```
  document.getElementById("#a").innerHTML='<input name='+field+' class="span2" id="prependedInput" onclick="" value="'+field_value2+'" type="text">'
```

For this code, How do I implement a datapicker only working on onclick attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling function fon `onclick` event.

**Example**

```
<input onclick="createdatepicker();"
```

now js function

```
function createdatepicker()
{
    //code to create date picker
}
```

Comment: in this case, "Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker' " says.

Comment: function createDate()
            {
                $('#prependedInput').datepicker();
            }

Comment: I call with onclick="createDate();"  but not working and give error: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  but same error again

Comment: So must be <input type='text' onclick='return createDate(this);' /> inside document.getElementById(#a).innerHTML ??

Comment: helpppppppppppppppppppppppp

Comment: ppleeaseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: @user2582546 Yes...`<input type='text' onclick='return createDate(this);' />` is correct inside document.getElement code

Comment: Again again "has no mathod datepicker" ://

Comment: @user2582546 add `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>` this two script at top of the page.